# How to apply a stroke/outline effect for QLabel

Tags: css, qt, qlabel

I did google and I know I can make it similar by drawing four times of shadows to achieve a similar effect. But isn't there a more straight-forward way or "correct" way to do it?

Note that I do need the font to be weight at 99 (actually I wish it could be much more than 99) I need super bold text with outline.

I cannot choose an extra bold font family since it should be customized by users.

I also find that the text stroke of css3 doesn't work with Qt (5.4).

Comment: What do you  mean with "css3 doesn't work with Qt"? That your code does not work ?

Comment: Qt's `QTextDocument` (and the classes that use it) does not implement HTML nor CSS. It implements something that resembles them both, but you cannot just read about CSS3 and assume it'll work in Qt. Qt's own documentation is the sole source of what's implemented.

Comment: You will need to paint the text yourself and then set it as a pixmap on the label. Or you can implement your own widget that paints itself so.

Comment: I thought that the stylesheet was css but I was wrong. Thanks for pointing this out. I did override paintEvent. I can get the text's path but how can I work on with that? How can I expand the stroke to more than one pixel, except for render multiple times?